# UIViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation argument fromInterfaceOrientation returning garbage value

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

When rotating the iPhone upside down during my tests, I found that while

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

gets called, the UIInterfaceOrientation parameter passed in as the argument is a garbage value (i.e. some random integer that is defined in the Apple documentation, instead of a UIInterfaceOrientation constant). How do I make it return a valid value?

Comment: How did you verify that it is a garbage value?

Comment: The debugger is returning something like 10190318313 instead of an enum constant. Or I may be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3):

It's not returning a garbage value.

Compare the value with the following constants:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
```

ie.

```
if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
     NSLog(@"PORTRAIT");
}
```

Or use the following BOOL macros:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation);
UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation);
```

ie.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation)) {
    NSLog(@"PORTRAIT");
}
```